# Why do canvas graphics not show up when using save and restore?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to test out rotation control for a video game, but when i implement save(); and restore(); nothing shows up. I dont know if this matters but the canvas is 500px by 500px;

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');

let x, y;
x = y = 0;
let degree = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
});

setInterval(() => {
  degree = Math.atan2(x - 250, -(y - 250));
  console.log(degree);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(250, 250);
  ctx.rotate(degree);
  ctx.fillRect(250, 250, 50, 20);
  ctx.restore();
},1000/60);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you're translating the rectangle to (250, 250) *and* drawing it at (250, 250), so the rectangle is off the screen.  Put another way, the save/restore is working fine, you just can't see the rectangle.

You're also not clearing the canvas when you render.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let x = 0, y = 0;
let degree = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
});

function render() {
  const degree = Math.atan2(x - 250, -(y - 250));
  console.log(degree);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Added.
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(250, 250);
  ctx.rotate(degree);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 20); // Changed.
  ctx.restore();
}

setInterval(() => requestAnimationFrame(render), 1000); // Changed.
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

As an aside, you should use `requestAnimationFrame` to render.  The code above adds it, but ideally you want your rendering to be based on the time that's elapsed since the last render.  That way you get the same speed across devices, regardless of the device's speed.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong right when you posted your answer. Thanks for the advice about requestAnimationFrame. :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, after some experimentation i have figured it out. because the origin was translated, the center of the screen became 0, 0. therefore the coordinates of the rectangle had to be changed to 0,0 to see it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  That's not quite true about the origin.  The origin is still (0, 0), but anything rendered will be translated and rotated inside the world.  Usually in graphics terms you talk about different "spaces" (screen space, world space, etc.).  It's common to have transformation matrices that move from one space to another to, e.g., figure out what object(s) in world space the mouse collides (mouse coords are in screen space), and the inversions of those matrices go the opposite way.